How to change text on your browser and make it permanent using Tampermonkey?
Im a complete js noob and just want to start off by trying to change text on my browser but make it permanent. I can already change the text by doing inspect element and then changing the text directly, but whenever you refresh the page reverts back to its original text. After some searching around I found this web extension called tampermonkey which supposedly runs a script to do it and update the words I want changed on any page I go to with the url, just for my browser only, but Im not sure how to write the script itself. Can anyone help me?
An example is, what script do I write to make the word Tacocat permenant using Tampermonkey?
enter image description here
I already tried following YT tutorials and such but nothing really changed on the website so just asking here, thanks!

What have you tried when following those tutorials?

Questions asking for code when providing none are not what this site is meant for, so this may get closed. For "low effort" questions (obviously it's not as you did try, but I can't think of a better term), Reddit or some other discussion-based site would be better as they do allow requests for code with none existing. The user script will eventually require upkeep, so your best bet is to learn at least the basics of HTML/CSS/JS for minimal inconvenience to yourself. There are people who'd be willing to build it, but they may not handle upkeep, or could be untrustworthy.

I don't use Tampermonkey, but yes Greasemonkey at lot. But the principle is the same.
Basically, you should wait for the whole page to load, then adapt according to your needs.
In the example you gave, you don't show how was the DOM before. But assuming that what you did, manually, was to set the content of the element "Hellothere" to "Tacocat", you would do like this:
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("Hellothere").innerText = "Tatocat";
}

Actually... it's as simple as that.
